# :nth-child(2n) of [attribute=value]

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a list with rows, each `li` has an attribute `data-status` which the value can be 1-5:

```
<ul>
    <li data-status="1"></li>
    <li data-status="2"></li>
    <li data-status="2"></li>
    <li data-status="1"></li>
    <li data-status="1"></li>
    <li data-status="2"></li>
    <li data-status="3"></li>
    <li data-status="4"></li>
    <li data-status="5"></li>
    <li data-status="5"></li>
    <li data-status="1"></li>
</ul>
```

I want each odd `li` that the `data-status` is 1 to be have a different background,
is it possible to do in CSS?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the question is ***how to select all the odd elements with a particular attribute ?***, then it is possible how explained in the other answers, with

```
li[data-status="1"]:nth-child(2n+1) {
   background: #f00;
}
```

or in an even easier way:

```
li[data-status="1"]:nth-child(odd) {
   background: #f00;
}
```

Take a look at [this good article](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) on how `nth-child` works.

If, instead, the question is ***how to select all the elements with a particular attribute, and then pick only the odd of that sub-list ?*** , well, that is not yet possible with CSS, but it will with **CSS Selectors Level 4**, as [explained here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#the-nth-match-pseudo), with the `nth-match()` pseudo-class:

```
:nth-match(An+B of <selector>)
```

that in your case would be

```
li:nth-match(2n+1 of [data-status="1"])
```

or

```
li:nth-match(odd of [data-status="1"])
```

Let's wait... CSS4 is coming !! :P

---

**EDIT**: as reported by Michael_B, [this feature has been stripped by CSS4 specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31415015/1654265), so stop waiting and start figuring another way to do it :/

Comment: I just checked [**Selectors 4 spec**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/). There is nothing called `nth-match()` defined therein. Maybe it was removed? Whatever the case, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ah, on further review, it was removed from the spec: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31415015/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B I knew this happened, but I forgot to come here updating the answer (and probably there are another couple of answer of mine to update)... I've did it now, thank you

Comment: @AndreaLigios, I was really hoping your answer worked! As I'm trying to craft an answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35355253/3597276 ... Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do

```
li[data-status="1"]:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f90;
}
```

There's a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/adamh/ggtff/

Comment: Absolutely works. I think this is a more common way to write it, though: `li[data-status="1"]:nth-child(2n+1)`

Comment: @BillCriswell thanks, absolutely right. I've reordered my selector

Comment: this does not work if you need to keep even/odd count of data-status="1" only, instead of generic odd-even of *all* rows

Comment: @AndreaLigios Yes, actually that's not possible in CSS, `nth-of-type` respects element but not `element[attr]` combination

Comment: @AndreaLigios if I understand you, I think it does - see my jsfiddle example in the answer above

Comment: @adam You can also make it more plain English just using `li[data-status="1"]:nth-child(odd) {}`

Comment: this is change the color for all the odd rows that the status=1, in my example it colors the: 1st, 3rd and 4th of the status=1 because those are odd rows.

Comment: Adam. Andrea is right here. We just got lucky with the <li> order. This is not working like we thought it was. =(

Answer (score 0):

If you're not against using jQuery you can use this approach.

```
$('li[data-status=1]').toggleClass(function(idx){
  return idx % 2 === 0 ? 'odd-status-one' : 'even-status-one'; 
});
```

Here's a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/arawur/3/edit